# django: routing users through a complex app with class-based views

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I'm an advanced beginner at django and python. I'm writing an app to handle registration and abstract submission for a conference, and I'm trying to use class-based views. Users get an emailed link that includes their registration code in the url. Starting at this url, users move through a series of views that collect all the necessary info.

The complication comes from the fact that users often stop half way through, and then want to complete the process several days or weeks later. This means that they might continue from the current page, or they might just click that original link. In addition, after several weeks they might have missed certain deadlines, so, e.g., they can no longer submit an abstract (but they can still register). Along the way, they have checked or unchecked various options that also influence the path they should take through the app.

My question is: where is the best place to put the logic that determines if the user is currently allowed to view that page, and if not, the best url to redirect them too? I thought I would create a custom view class that, e.g., overrides the dispatch method to include global checks (e.g., is conference registration open?), and then subclasses could add additional checks (e.g., has the user entered all the necessary info for her abstract?).  The problem I ran into was that the checks were run in the wrong order (I want base class checks run first). I then started investigating custom view decorators or custom middleware. At this point I realized I could use some expert advice about which approach to take. (If it matters, I am not using the django authentication system.) Thanks in advance.

Comment: You know you don't *have* to [reinvent](http://hewitt.gotdns.org/djconf.html) [the](https://launchpad.net/django-conference) [wheel](http://www.eventbrite.co.uk/)...

Comment: @danodonovan: Thanks for that link. My app is already written and in use with function-based views. I'm updating it right now, and thought I would try to use class-based views with a better routing solution. Also, in my app abstracts are entered via a series of forms, rather than a file upload, which allows the app to format the conference program. DjConf has some cool features, though, which I might copy!

Comment: More discussion of this problem here: http://www.reddit.com/r/django/comments/17wx2m/where_should_logic_live_in_a_django_saas_project/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the [form wizard](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/) could help you managing the viewing sequence.

In general [django greybeards](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.0/topics/db/models/#model-methods) advocate keeping row-wise logic in `Models`, and table-wise logic in `Managers`, so it seems appropriate to keep complex view logic in a master view class.

The wizard class can help maintain the order of the views, but to resume an out-dated session you may need to do some model saves (which could get too complex very quickly) or some cookie handling.

In the past, when presented with a similar situation, I took the simplest route and separated *user* registration and the task that the user wants to perform (event registration). The user registers *once* but if they fluff up the event registration, they just have to log back in at a later date and do it again (their hassle - not yours!).

Comment: Thanks for the further comments. I initially evaluated the form wizard, but decided I needed a more general solution to handle the complexities of our registration/submission process, which involves multiple co-authors, institutions, registrant types, etc.